# From what source does etherscan.io aggregate and broadcast data that appears on the blockchain ledger?

Tags: blockchain, etherscan, blocks, hash

as blocks are hashed together as transactions pile up and are broadcasted on the Ethereum blockchain, how exactly does the website etherscan.io in turn publish and broadcast all that information in real-time? Is etherscan.io an API in and of itself? If so, what source is it tapping into: *Where* and how is it getting its blockchain data?

In my opinion, etherscan.io is *not* the blockchain itself, but is somehow aggregating and collecting transactions as they happen on the blockchain, and then publishes them on the world wide web. My question is, how does this website do this? What is the *source* it is tapping in to to extract real-time information from the Ethereum blockchain?

Comment: They just run their own client node and keep it in sync with the rest of the network. All the details they publish on their site can either be read directly from the chain data stored by all (full) clients, or calculated from it.

Comment: what are client nodes

Comment: The software you run (e.g. Geth) if you want to be a part of the network without using a third-party middleman (e.g. Metamask/Infura) -> https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/

Comment: if Metamask is a middle man, which software is it running? Geth?

Comment: By default Metamask connects to a backend called Infura, run by Consensys. Looking at their FAQ, it does indeed run Geth -> https://infura.io/faq

Comment: so by me running Geth software, you're saying I would not only be a client node, but also could create my own web wallet instead of Metamask? Instead of being a wallet though, etherscan.io is simply piggybacking the data privileges from being a client node by sharing what it sees publicly? meaning that anything else that is a client node (including me and MetaMask), can see the same data that etherscan sees, and we could even turn ourselves into a blockchain explorer website as well?

Comment: Yep, all correct. I'm sure Etherscan has plenty of proprietary data analytics that it runs, but it is indeed running those analyses over the same data that everyone else can see.